# Quōmodo rēctē "derivative of f(x)" dīcere?

Tags: vocabulary, new-latin, english-to-latin-translation, mathematics

I am currently struggling to figure out how to translate the following phrase:

> [...] derivative of *f(x)* [...]

I had a couple of initial ideas, namely:

> 1. dēductīva [fūnctiō] dē *f(x)*
> 2. dēductīva [fūnctiō] fūnctiōnis de *x*
> 3. dēductīva [fūnctiō] fūnctiōnis *f(x)*

And while these are (IIRC) correct Latin phrases, I am unsure as to whether or not they are similar (or the same as) the ways in which authors in mathematics (e.g, Leonhard Euler, Isaac Newton, etc.) would have expressed it.

In short, what is the "proper/idiomatic" way in which the phrase "derivative of *f(x)*" should be translated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that our modern notation was invented by Leibniz, who used the term "differentia", abbreviated as d. Someone ought to look up Leibniz's mathematical writings, which are in Latin.

Some discussion here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/use-of-h-in-the-newton-quotient/1917#1917

Comment: The Wikipedia article uses _diferentia_ to express _dx_, and not the derivative itself, which is _df(x)/dx_.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivativum) defines derivative as *derivativum*. So maybe  *derivativum de f(x)* would do.

Now, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derivativus#Latin), derivativum is the neuter, nominative, singular of the noun *derivativus*, from which the English derivative comes from. However, the mathematical derivative is a noun, not an adjective. So I think we could **not** just translate the declination of the adjective, and write something like *derivativi f(x)*. However, if we decline it as other nouns ending in "-um", like *[somnium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/somnium)*, then *derivativi f(x)* might be in fact correct.

PS: I'm just a beginner. Beware.

Comment: AFAIK in this context it'd be okay to use *deductiva* as a substantive with *functio* being implied (i.e, *deductiva functio*).